# Build a Matrix style Grid of User Permission Setting with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, acl

I've been tasked with adding in a link/menu dashboard for my work.  It needs to have user permissions to view/not view each link record on a per user basis.

Most time this is done with user groups, I need to do it per-user for per-link.

I have started by using a middle database table to join `users` and `links` as well as hold the user permission if they are allowed to view each link.  I will show the Database design below.

What I need help with is build a table/grid to mass set permissions for each user on each menu link.

I would like to do it similar to this image below...

[View full size image](https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2015/2015-04-23_15-07-37.png)
[image]

So I need to pull in users from the database and the links from the database as well as the permission records.

Build a grid with users in the vertical column and links in the horizontal.

The permissions setting will then fill in the grid spaces and I think it would be best to have a simple Form Selection field for a yes/no value.

Admin can change permissions for each user and submit the form which will need to then update every Permission record!

Here is what my 3 demo database tables look like...

**Links table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `text` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `link` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `permission` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

**User table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

**Permission table: user_link_permissions **

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_link_permissions` (
`id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `link_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `permission` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Where I need some help...**

I am not sure how to best generate the Grid of Users, Links, and Permissions.

As well as how submitting all that data could be processed in the backend to save all settings.

I will post more progress as it comes but right now I could use some direction please?

I realize i'll need to query and get all `users` as well as all `links` and then all `user_link_permissions` but I am at a loss as to how to create this grid and make it all correspond with the correct values, etc.

UPDATE:

I just found this link which seems to do something similar which looks like a good reference.  It even saves the grid value with AJAX which should simplify things and load I believe.  http://runastartup.com/how-to-update-a-mysql-field-in-a-multi-table-matrix/

Comment: I found an awesome resource here http://runastartup.com/how-to-update-a-mysql-field-in-a-multi-table-matrix/ which helped me build it, even using AJAX to save each individual user setting as they are changed...I will post my answer of what I came up with, due to the help of that article.  I could not find much info on Google with this question so I think this will help others in the future